# PowerShell 3.0 - Setting Affinity to CPU per USER's PROCESS

Tags: powershell, set, cpu, affinity

my first post here. I am working on a script using powerShell, the objective is to set a certain amount of CPU-threads per USER's process, using the forum here, i was able to find most of the answers, and even got my script to run, except, if it sets the affinity, it sets it to EVERY-Process, not just the user i need.
here is the code(with comments):

```
# GET LIST of all process running
$pList = get-wmiobject win32_process

# loop through created array and get the OWNER of the processes
foreach ($p in $pList) {
    #If "myUserName" is found:
    if ($p.getowner().User -eq 'myUserName') {
        # get process name
        $procName = $p.ProcessName
        # trim STRING to remove EXE
        $procName = $procName.Replace('.exe','')
        # use get-process to make array of processes run by "myUserName"
        $activeProc = Get-Process -name $procName
        # Loop to set affinity for each process

        foreach ($i in $activeProc){
            $i.ProcessorAffinity=0xFE
        }
    }
}
```

when i execute this command, all of the process are set to new Thread Count, 
any suggestions how to make it ONLY adjust threads for SPECIFIC user?

Thanks a lot guys!
this is pretty urgent.

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, this is not setting affinity for **every process on the machine**, it's setting it for **every process with the same name as one the user is running**.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `get-process -name $procName` you are finding all processes that *have the same name* as one run by the user.

Instead of using the `ProcessName`, use `ProcessId`.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell version 4.0, you can use the `-IncludeUserName` parameter on the `Get-Process` cmdlet. Once you have a list of processes, you can then filter then using the `Where-Object` cmdlet, which has a default alias of `?`.

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where-Object -FilterScript { $PSItem.UserName -match 'system' };
```

Or short-hand might look like this:

```
gps -inc | ? { $_.UserName -match 'system' };
```

**Note**: Using the `-IncludeUserName` parameter requires privilege elevation.